# Plugin that controls Grid or Matrix layout when entering data in backend

Tags: matrix, grid

I have a field that can use either Grid or Matrix. It has 10 Asset file uploads and 2 text input fields. The layout in the backend gets a little messy and hard to read when a user is entering data. Is there a plugin out there that allows you to handle the layout of either Grid or Matrix in the backend when a user is entering the data or are we stuck with the horizontal scroll?